# Collaborating on answers

Tags: feature-request, answers

I sometimes have a good idea writing an answer but one part is missing (which i don't know how to do it).

For that i would like to have a kind of "collaborative" answer which might have more than just one person who answers but two or more persons. So even more great answers could be generated.

Is there such a possibility?

If not, i would love to have it. If the answer is correct, everybody who contributed could receive reputation from that.

What do you guys think about this?

Comment: I really like this idea! Especially for more extensive topics like Geometry Nodes, this would be a great help and could lead to great answers. Especially GN currently shows the tendency that many topics are really extensive or even similar, and then a fragmentation of questions/answers arises, whereby the quality of this platform suffers enormously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to indicate that the answer is a collaborative effort, you can mark it as a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

[image: Community Wiki]

Comment: I should add that community wiki answers do not contribute to the reputation of the authors. The moderators also do not have the ability to add or change existing features, that's up to Stack Exchange Inc.